# cx_Freeze - how do I convert multiple files into the build folder

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I've made a program which launches another python program using `os.startfile()`.

I wanted to have this as two `exe` files, launching the second by using `subprocess.call()` instead, in 1 build folder but I don't know how to do this.

I tried making a setup file for both, creating 2 build folders and then copying 1 of the `exe` files into the other's build folder but got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 12, 
in <module> __import__(name + "__init__") 
ImportError: No module named 'menu_record__init__'
```

Have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to include two exe in one build with the following method:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

options = {
'build_exe': {'path': sys.path + ['modules']}
}

executables = [
    Executable('script_1.py'),
    Executable('script_2.py')]

setup(
    name='two exe in one folder',
    version='0.1',
    description='Two exe in a single build folder',
    options=options,
    executables=executables)
```

You will probably have to edit this script further but it should produce two exe in the same build folder.

An example can be found if you go to your python location (where python.exe is) and navigate to the 
**Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced** location where you should find a script called setup.py, take a look at it, your answer should be there.

The exe in Cx_Freeze have dependencies.  By copying the exe you are only copying part of the program.

Comment: This [Post's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172483/python-cx-freeze-for-two-or-more-python-files-modules) answer mentions it.

Answer (score 1):

A program created by `cx_Freeze` isn't a single exe file. It's the entire folder created under the build folder. If you just copy the exe file, you are only copying part of the program.

Instead of trying to have two exe files in the same folder, what you should do is have two folders, each being a complete `cx_Freeze` program. Your subprocess call should be calling `../program2/program2.exe` instead of just `./program2.exe`.

Comment: You don't need to. You just need to make sure that you compile all the python files you wish to include in one build folder using the same script.